# better way to query in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Is there a better way to do this

```
questionobjects = Questions.objects.all()
for questionobject in questionobjects:
        answerobjects = Answers.objects.filter(question=questionobject.id).count()
```

In the above query `Answers` model has foreign key relation with `Questions`. But in the above  script the query Answer query executes based on the number of questionobjects.

Suppose there are 10 questionobjects then 10 separate answerobject queries take place. Is there a way to do this with a single query because as the number of questionobjects increases, it will be a problem because the number of answerobjects queries also increase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it looks like you just care about the count of answers, rather than getting the actual answer objects. You can do this with annotations:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Question.objects.all().annotate(Count('answers'))
```

Comment: how to write the above query to get questionobjects whose  answers count is greater than 3

Comment: i know how do that using a sql query but iam new to django and have issues with it

Comment: @ChingChong https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

Comment: @ChingChong `Questions.objects.annotate(count=Count('answers')).filter(count__gt=3)`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at annotation: [Django Annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)

```
from django.db.models import Count
questions = Questions.objects.annotate(count=Count('answers'))
```

Then you can access the count with `[q.count for q in questions]`